# Датчик влажности "HIH-4000"

Tags: arduino, микроконтроллеры, avr

Для чего подключен нагрузочный резистор(на 80кОм) между выходным сигналом и землёй ?
[image: датчик влажности]
[ссылка на более подробне описание датчика](https://www.dnatechindia.com/honeywell-hih4000-humidity-sensor.html)

Comment: Там же написано "минимальная нагрузка", то есть обеспечение течения тока минимум 5V / 80kOhm = 62.5uA.

Answer (score 1):

Для корректной работы датчика.

Видимо, производитель не смог разместить нужное сопротивление внутри корпуса. Возможно из-за габаритов, возможно из-за тепловых помех.

Судя по величине, это похоже на pull-down-резистор, т.е. стравливающий паразитный потенциал с сигнальной линии на нулевую. Но учитывая, что датчик емкостный, оно может быть частью RC-фильтра. А также может быть плечом резисторного делителя напряжения. Но, не зная устройства датчика, точно сказать невозможно.